# Error en mysqli, cómo se puede resolver?

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy haciendo un formulario y a la hora de que se envíen los datos me salta el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\assets\php\send.php:173 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\assets\php\send.php(173): mysqli_stmt->bind_param('David', 'Garcia', 'Velezqez@gmail....', '667098123', 'Camero', 'No') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\assets\php\send.php on line 173

No entiendo por qué da ese error ya que estoy enviando mediante POST todas las variables :/

PHP:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$movil = $_POST['movil'];
$puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
$seleccion = $_POST['seleccion'];
        /* crear una sentencia preparada */
        $insertarDatos =  "INSERT INTO register(nombre,apellido,email,movil,puesto,seleccion) VALUES('$nombre','$apellido','$email','$movil','$puesto','$seleccion')";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($insertarDatos);
        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->bind_param($nombre,$apellido,$email,$movil,$puesto,$seleccion);
            /* ejecutar la consulta */
            $stmt->execute();
            $msgOutput="Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->affected_rows;
            /* cerrar sentencia */
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            $msgOutput="Error preparando la consulta: ".$conn->error;
        }
        /* cerrar conexión */
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        $msgOutput="Error, no se pudo conectar a la base de datos: ".$conn->connect_error;
    }
} else {
    $msgOutput="No se postearon los datos correctamente";
}
echo $msgOutput;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="formulario">
        <span class="recuerde">   <i class="fas fa-lock"></i> Recuerde que toda su información se encuentra encriptada.      </span>
        <form class="postulacion" method="POST" action="./assets/php/send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form_nombre">
                <label for="nombre">
                    ¿Cuál es su nombre? Ponga únicamente su primer nombre.
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" maxlength="20" title="Introduzca un nombre correcto." required />
            </div>
            <div class="form_apellido">
                <label for="apellido">
                    ¿Cuál es su apellido? <span class="info_apellido">Ponga solo su primer apellido</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="apellido" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" maxlength="20" title="Introduzca un apellido correcto." required />
            </div>
            <div class="form_email">
                <label for="email">
                    ¿Cuál es su e-mail? <span class="info_email">Solo lo usaremos para enviarte actualizaciones sobre tu postulación. </span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" title="Introduzca un email correcto." maxlength="30" onBlur="comprobarEmail()" required />
                 <span id="estadoemail"></span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_movil">
                <label for="numero">
                    ¿Cuál es su número de teléfono? <span class="info_numero">Lo necesitaremos para ponernos en contacto contigo. </span>
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="form_movilz" name="movil" pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="12" title="Introduzca un número de teléfono correcto, sin el +34" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form_puesto">
                <label for="puesto">
                    ¿Para qué puesto aspiras?
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="puesto" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" maxlength="20" title="Introduzca un puesto de trabajo correcto." required />
            </div>
            <div class="form_cv">
                <label for="cv">
                    Suba su curriculum
                </label>
                <input type="file" name="tous" value="Adjuntar" title="Adjunte un archivo." size="150" maxlength="150" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form_salario">
                <label for="salario">
                    ¿Deseas recibir el salario por adelantado?
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="Sí" title="Seleccione una opción." required />
                <label for="seleccion">Sí</label>
                <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="No" title="Seleccione una opción." required />
                <label for="seleccion">No</label>
            </div>


            <button class="form_send" id="form_sende" type="submit" name="submit">Enviar Formulario</button>


        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se origina de que no estás construyendo tu consulta preparada de la manera adecuada.

1. No deberías pasar valores directo a la estructura de la query sino usar [marcadores de parámetros](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) por medio del símbolo **`?`** (*ya que como esta actualmente no solo genera el error expuesto sino que además pierde significado trabajar con *prepared statements*.*)
2. Dichos marcadores deben corresponder en cantidad a las variables que pases en el método **`bindParam`**

   ```
   prepare("INSERT INTO tabla (columna1, columna2,.......) VALUES (?, ?, .......)")
   ```
3. Por otro lado aunque el valor por default es *string*, considero que deberías pasar como primer argumento los tipos de datos de cada variable recibida y que será usada posteriormente al hacer binding en el [método **`bind_param`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

   ```
   bind_param("los tipos de datos", las variables);
   ```

Comment: Problema solucionado.
Gracias!